# Complejidad de algoritmo

Tags: python

```
#Obtengo el indice del segundo valor que es >= Punto
def terceraParte(inter,i,j,punto):
    if j == i+1:
        res = inter[j:]
    else:
        p = int((i+j)/2)
        if inter[p][1] > punto:
            res = terceraParte(inter,i,p,punto)
        elif inter[p][1] <= punto:
            res = terceraParte(inter,p,j,punto)
    return res

p3 = terceraParte(intervalos,0,len(intervalos),17)
print(p3)
```

Quiero obtener de la siguiente lista: [10,20,21] el primer indice que supere un punto, por ejemplo, 17. El resultado sería 20.

El problema me funciona cuando punto = 17, pero no cuando el punto = 9.
¿Porque?

Comment: que es intervalos ? recuerda ser especifico y realizar preguntas enbase a [ask], saludos!

Comment: Editado. Tengo una lista [1,5,10,15,20,25] y mi objetivo es que yo le de un punto, por ejemplo el 12 y me devuelva el indice mayor mas cercano a 12, el 15.

Comment: que valor le das a i al llamar la función segundaParte() y cual es su objetivo???

Comment: Le doy el valor de 0, para ir recorriendo hasta el final de la lista.

Comment: cuando lista[i] >= punto: estas tomando como valor el indice, debe ser el valor dentro del array, revisa la respuesta. @user9513683

Comment: ¿Se puede asumir que la lista está ordenada? Porque en este caso deberías considerar usar (o implementar) [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)

Comment: Yo opinaría que es mejor ordenarla y usar la búsqueda binaria, ya que esta es de complejidad O(Log(N)).

Comment: @David.O Efectivamente, esa es mi intención pero no se hacerlo

Comment: ¿por qué la pregunta se titula "complejidad de algoritmo?" Habría que cambiar el título o explicar dentro la relación con el título

Answer (score 4):

Si tal y como comentas partes de un **array ordenado**, lo que necesitas efectivamente es implementar una **búsqueda binaria**. En el per de los casos necesita ***O***(log n) iteraciones, siendo ***O***(1) en cuanto a uso de memoria. En tu código actual el problema está en la línea `inter[p][1]` donde `inter[p]` es un entero, por lo que estás intentando indexar sobre un escalar.

No obstante, usar un algoritmo recursivo es menos legible, menos eficiente (más aún si haces copias de la lista de por medio con `inter[j:]`) y puedes terminar superando el límite de recursión.

Una aproximación iterativa creo que es más sencilla de entender e implementar. La idea de la búsqueda binaria es muy simple, partiendo de un indice superior y otro inferior entre los que buscas:

- Si el indice inferior es mayor que el superior, la búsqueda termina sin encontrar el valor.
- Buscamos el índice del elemento situando en el medio, siendo este  igual a  `(indice_superior + indice_inferior ) // 2`. Dónde `//` es la división entera.
- Si el elemento medio es menor al elemento buscado el indice inferior se iguala al indice del elemento medio más 1.
- Si el elemento medio es superior al buscado, el límite superior pasa a ser el indice del elemento medio menos 1.
- Si el elemento medio es igual al elemento buscado retornamos el elemento. En caso contrario volvemos al paso dos.

En este caso no estamos buscando el item, buscamos el que es inmediatamente superior a él. La idea no obstante es la misma. Una posible implementación sería:

```
def busqueda_binaria(inter, punto, inf=0, sup=None):

    # Si la lista está vacía retronamos None
    if not inter:
        return None

    # Si el índice superior es None se busca hasta el final de la lista
    if sup is None:
        sup = len(inter) - 1

    while inf < sup:
        medio = (sup + inf) // 2
        if inter[medio] <= punto:
            inf = medio + 1
        else:
            sup = medio

    return None if inter[inf] <= punto else inter[inf]
```

Si se quiere el índice basta con cambiar el `return` por `return None if inter[inf] <= punto else inf`

Algunos test:

```
>>> busqueda_binaria([10, 20, 21], 17)
20
>>> busqueda_binaria([10, 20, 21], 9)
10
>>> busqueda_binaria([10, 20, 21, 30], 17, inf=2)
21
>>> busqueda_binaria([2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 30, 32, 35], 8, inf=5, sup=8)
20
>>> busqueda_binaria([2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 30, 32, 35], 36, inf=5, sup=8)
>>> busqueda_binaria([], 4)
```

Ambos índices son inclusivos, si elemento no se encuentra o la lista no tiene elementos se retorna `None`.

Si hacemos un pequeño test de una búsqueda típica iterando desde el primer elemento hasta que encontremos el que buscamos (`for elemento in lista:`) frente a la búsqueda binaria nos encontramos con una diferencia significativa, especialmente en el peor de los casos para la primera aproximación, aquel en el que tiene que recorrer todo el iterable porque no existe un elemento mayor:

> Longitud de lista:  100000000 elementos.
>     Binaria:  0.014013051986694336 segundos.
>     For:     14.315513372421265    segundos.

Para este mismo ejemplo pero para el mejor caso posible para la iteración simple (el primer elemento ya es mayor) y uno de los peores para la búsqueda binaria (el elemento se encuentra en los extremos), la sobrecarga de la búsqueda binaria es proporcionalmente insignificante, 27 iteraciones.

---

**Edición:**

Si requieres que sea recursivo, la misma lógica anterior se puede aplicar:

```
def terceraParte(lista, i, j, punto):
    if i >= j:
        if i < len(lista) and lista[i] > punto:
            return lista[i]
        return None

    else:
        p = (i+j)//2
        if lista[p] <= punto:
            return terceraParte(lista, p+1, j, punto)
        else:
            return terceraParte(lista, i, p , punto)
```

Si quieres el índice cambia `return lista[i]` por `return i` simplemente.

Answer (score -1):

El problema lo tienes aquí:

```
   if lista[i] >= punto:
        res = i
```

Cuando se cumple : `lista[i] >= punto` , en realidad debes igualar al valor dentro del array no al valor del indice (`i`), esto para obtener el valor correcto:

```
    if lista[i] >= punto:
        res = lista[i]
```

Este sería el código correcto:

```
lista = [1,5,10,15,20,25]

#Obtengo el indice del primer valor que es >= Punto
def segundaParte(lista,i,punto):
    if i == len(lista):
        res = - 1
    else:
        if lista[i] >= punto:
            res = lista[i] #***Correccion aqui!
        else:
            res = segundaParte(lista,i+1,punto)
    return res


print segundaParte(lista,0,12);
```

Comment: El funcionamiento del código es el corrector pero O(nlogn), quiero pasarlo a O(logn) puesto que actualmente recorre toda la lista.

Comment: Veo que acaba de entrar mi fan numero 1 a ponerme negativo a esta respuesta.

Comment: @user9513682 no recorre toda la lista, en cuanto encuentra que lista[i] >= punto: entonces termina el bucle, o a que te refieres?